# I want to store state of call being made in firestore , incoming and outgoing state saving perfectly but missed not working

Tags: android, google-cloud-firestore, call-recording

I am making a call recording application and want to store call details in firestore. All is working fine but missed call state details not saving in database while incoming and outgoing details are saved perfectly. I'm passing final_state in recordservice.class where firebase obj is created. Here's a screenshot how I am saving data in firestore- [recordservice.class where firestore object is made](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i1uUJ.png) . Any help would be great. Thank you

```
package com.example.myapplicationcall;

import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.ContentResolver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.provider.Settings;
import android.telephony.TelephonyManager;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.List;

public class PhoneStateReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    static final String TAG = "State";
    static final String TAG1 = " Inside State";
    static Boolean recordStarted;
    static final String TAG2 = " Device name";
    public static String phoneNumber;
    public static String name;
    public static String stateStr;
    private static boolean isIncoming;
    private static boolean ring =false;
    public static String deviceName;
    public static String device_name;
    public  static int final_state;
    public static boolean callReceived=false;
    public static int missstate;
    private static int lastState = TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

         ContentResolver res = (ContentResolver)context.getContentResolver();
        deviceName = Settings.System.getString(res, "device_name");
        Log.e(TAG2, "system device_name: " + deviceName);

        BluetoothAdapter myDevice = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
        device_name = myDevice.getName();
        Log.e(TAG2, "bluethooth device_name: " + device_name);

        SharedPreferences pref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
        Boolean switchCheckOn = pref.getBoolean("switchOn", true);
        if (switchCheckOn) {
            System.out.println("Receiver Start");

            if (intent.getAction().equals("android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL")) {
                phoneNumber = intent.getExtras().getString("android.intent.extra.PHONE_NUMBER");
                Log.d(TAG, "state:" + phoneNumber);

            } else {
                 stateStr = intent.getExtras().getString(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);
                String phoneNumber = intent.getExtras().getString(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER);
               int state = 0;
                //int state;
                if (stateStr.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_IDLE)) {
                    state = TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE;

                    int k = pref.getInt("numOfCalls", 1);
                    pref.edit().putInt("numOfCalls", --k).apply();
                    int l = pref.getInt("numOfCalls", 0);
                    Log.d(TAG1, " Inside " + stateStr);
                    recordStarted = pref.getBoolean("recordStarted", false);
                    Log.d(TAG1, " recordStarted in idle :" + recordStarted);
                    if (recordStarted && l == 0) {
                        Log.d(TAG1, " Inside to stop recorder " + stateStr);
                        context.stopService(new Intent(context, RecorderService.class));
                        pref.edit().putBoolean("recordStarted", false).apply();
                    }
                } else if (stateStr.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_OFFHOOK)) {
                    state = TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK;

                    int j = pref.getInt("numOfCalls", 0);
                    pref.edit().putInt("numOfCalls", ++j).apply();
                    Log.d(TAG, "onReceive: num of calls " + pref.getInt("numOfCalls", 0));
                    Log.d(TAG1, " recordStarted in offhook: " + recordStarted);
                    Log.d(TAG1, " Inside " + stateStr);

                    phoneNumber = intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER);
                    Log.d(TAG1, " Phone Number in receiver " + phoneNumber);
                    if (pref.getInt("numOfCalls", 1) == 1) {
                        Intent reivToServ = new Intent(context, RecorderService.class);
                        reivToServ.putExtra("number", phoneNumber);
                        reivToServ.putExtra("try_state",stateStr);

                        Log.d("fatal", "onReceive: " + reivToServ.toString());
                        try {
                            context.startService(reivToServ);
                        } catch (IllegalStateException ex) {
                            Log.d("fatal", "onReceive: " + ex.toString());
                        }
                        //name=new CommonMethods().getContactName(phoneNumber,context);
                        int serialNumber = pref.getInt("serialNumData", 1);
                        new DatabaseManager(context).addCallDetails(new CallDetails(serialNumber, phoneNumber, new CommonMethods().getTIme(), new CommonMethods().getDate()));

                        List<CallDetails> list = new DatabaseManager(context).getAllDetails();
                        for (CallDetails cd : list) {
                            String log = "Serial Number : " + cd.getSerial() + " | Phone num : " + cd.getNum() + " | Time : " + cd.getTime1() + " | Date : " + cd.getDate1();
                            Log.d("Database ", log);
                        }
                        //recordStarted=true;
                        pref.edit().putInt("serialNumData", ++serialNumber).apply();
                        pref.edit().putBoolean("recordStarted", true).apply();
                    }
                } else if (stateStr.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING)) {
                    state = TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING;

                }
                Log.d(TAG1, "STATE IS " + state);
                Log.d(TAG1,"OTHER STATE IS:"+stateStr);
                onCallStateChanged(context, state, phoneNumber);
            }
        }
    }
                public void onCallStateChanged (Context context,int state, String number){

                    if (lastState == state) {
                        //No change, debounce extras
                        return ;
                    }
                    switch (state) {
                        case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING:
                            isIncoming = true;
                           // ring = true;
                            phoneNumber = number;
                          //  Toast.makeText(context, "Incoming Call Ringing", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            final_state = state;
                            Log.d(TAG1,"Test state:"+final_state);
                            break;

                        case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK:
                            //callReceived = true;
                            //Transition of ringing->offhook are pickups of incoming calls.  Nothing done on them
                            if (lastState != TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING) {
                                isIncoming = false;

                                //    Toast.makeText(context, "Outgoing Call Started", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                final_state = state;
                            }
                                Log.d(TAG1,"ANOTHER:"+final_state);
                            //}

                            break;
                        case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE:


                            if (lastState == TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING) {
                                //Ring but no pickup-  a miss

                             //   phoneNumber = intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER);
                                Intent missget = new Intent(context,RecorderService.class);
                                missget.putExtra("number",phoneNumber);

                                try {
                                    context.startService(missget);
                                } catch (IllegalStateException ex) {
                                    Log.d("fatal", "onMISS: " + ex.toString());
                                }
                                SharedPreferences preef = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
                                int serialNumber = preef.getInt("serialNumData", 1);
                                new DatabaseManager(context).addCallDetails(new CallDetails(serialNumber, phoneNumber, new CommonMethods().getTIme(), new CommonMethods().getDate()));

                                List<CallDetails> list = new DatabaseManager(context).getAllDetails();
                                for (CallDetails cd : list) {
                                    String log = "Serial Number : " + cd.getSerial() + " | Phone num : " + cd.getNum() + " | Time : " + cd.getTime1() + " | Date : " + cd.getDate1();
                                    Log.d("Database ", log);
                                }
                                //recordStarted=true;
                                preef.edit().putInt("serialNumData", ++serialNumber).apply();
                                preef.edit().putBoolean("recordStarted", true).apply();

                                    Toast.makeText(context, "Ringing but no pickup" + phoneNumber, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    //missstate = state;
                                    final_state = state;
                                    Log.d(TAG1, "CHECKING" + final_state);

                                }



                            break;
                    }
                    lastState = state;
                    Log.d(TAG1,"last state:"+lastState);
                }

}
```